# Hibernate with Struts2 or spring mvc?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate goes well with which framework struts2 or springmvc ?
Please if possible provide a comparison

Thanx

Comment: I will use Hibernate 2 for database access in my project but still not sure which framework to use .Have read that Hibernate goes well with spring mvc .

Comment: Plus you told not struts2 if you can give some details why not struts2 would be great

Comment: No will use either Struts2 or spring mvc

Comment: Well Spring MVC will have MVC structure. where the complexity will be less and even u can use struts2 with hibernate but most Spring MVC and Hibernate used for the Application.

Comment: We are just using JPA and Struts2...y dont you think of JPA instead of hibernate..???